# When do I need mapbox.js?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am trying to figure out whether I really need to use mapbox.js, or whether leaflet is sufficient for a mapping project. We will probably be hosting data and tiles ourselves (not basemaps).

Where can I find a list of features provided by mapbox.js? I know, for example, that mapbox.js provides support for UTFGrid and TileJSON.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapbox.js provides a convenient way to consume Mapbox services — tiles, geocoding, markers, etc — and helps developers comply with licensing/attribution terms automatically. It also looks like it adds some design scaffolding.

Anything prefixed with `L.mapbox` in [the API documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/) is custom, but all features of Leaflet are still available.

You might also be interested in [the launch blog post](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-js-with-leaflet/), which explains some of the reasons for moving to Leaflet for Mapbox.js.